# Display SVG keeping the original font-size

Tags: css, svg

i have several svg's included in and image tag on my homepage.

My svg's are resized to the parent div container, which is 30em's wide.
My problem now is that i have svg's are not of the same width and all of them are scaled to a width of 30em.

See this example:
jsfiddle.net/xpgz44oL/

The displayed font-size should be the same for every svg.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: svg is a image it will resize when the parent is resized

Comment: That's not helpful.
I am searching for a way to get the originaö font size out of the svg and also the resized font size.
With this factor i can simply set the size of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original drawings were done at the same scale, you could look at the viewBox widths and set each image to that width (or a multiple of that width if you want them bigger).

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://www.austrokamin.at/media/dw/zeichnungen/laengenelement-1000mm-dw-zeichnung.svg" width="158.95px"/>
    <img src="http://www.austrokamin.at/media/dw/zeichnungen/dachdurchfuehrung-20-35-grad-dw-zeichnung.svg" width="239.19"/>
</div>
```